# In clickhouse, How to return null for nullable column when using cast function

Tags: clickhouse

Suppose I have a table named x1 with column c1 which is 'Int32' nullable, I want to cast it to 'Int64' using 'CAST' function. I found 'CAST' function doesn't support nullable value, so I have to convert null value first with following command:
`SELECT CAST(assumeNotNull(c1), 'Int64')`
It works but returns 0 for NULL value, I can't use 'nullIf()' either because it will handle ZERO value wrong.

**How can I get NULL when casting nullable value?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select arrayJoin( [Null::Nullable(Int32), 42::Nullable(Int32)] ) x, 
cast(x, 'Nullable(Int64)') r, 
toInt64(x) r1　;
┌────x─┬────r─┬───r1─┐
│ ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │ ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │ ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │
│   42 │   42 │   42 │
└──────┴──────┴──────┘

desc(select arrayJoin( [Null::Nullable(Int32), 42::Nullable(Int32)] ) x, 
cast(x, 'Nullable(Int64)') r, 
toInt64(x) r1　);
┌─name─┬─type────────────┬
│ x    │ Nullable(Int32) │
│ r    │ Nullable(Int64) │
│ r1   │ Nullable(Int64) │
└──────┴─────────────────┴
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select arrayJoin( [Null::Nullable(Int32), 42::Nullable(Int32)] ) x, ifNull(x,0)::Int64 r　;
┌────x─┬──r─┐
│ ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │  0 │
│   42 │ 42 │
└──────┴────┘

desc(select arrayJoin( [Null::Nullable(Int32), 42::Nullable(Int32)] ) x, ifNull(x,0)::Int64 r　);
┌─name─┬─type────────────┬─
│ x    │ Nullable(Int32) │
│ r    │ Int64           │
└──────┴─────────────────┴─
```